# The package javax is not accessible

Tags: java, import

`import javax.speech.*;`
`import javax.speech.recognition.*;`

I get an error saying (see title), because of these.
Where do I get javax and I've see there are different versions which do I get.

Thanks

Comment: Java and JavaScript are 2 different languages. I changed the tag in your question so that people with actual knowledge of Java can see it; be sure to choose the correct one next time

Comment: See https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/speech-api-frequently-asked-questions.html#implementation . You need to download an actual implementation of the API and put it in your classpath to use it.